# What happens when the Dominate Monster or Geas spells end?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mind-control

*Dominate Monster* and *Geas* allow to control a person (in different ways) and make then do things that you want, with some constraints.

The spell descriptions do not say what happens when the spells end: Does the target know that he acted according to the caster will and not on his own? What does he remember about when he was affected by the spell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## They remember everything

First, spells do what they say they do. None of these spells state that they suppress the consciousness or awareness of the victim in any way. I very much doubt that doing so would be the default (if we can even speak of something like that in the case of magic) and it should be understood from the context alone as obvious, so that it would not merit a mention.

This is also supported by the existence of the Enchanter Wizard feature Alter Memories:

> When you cast an enchantment spell to charm one or more creatures, you
> can alter one creature's understanding so that it remains unaware of
> being charmed. Additionally, once before the spell expires, you can
> use your action to try to make the chosen creature forget some of the
> time it spent charmed. (PHB 117)

If you want to achieve the effect you describe, consider being an Enchanter.

Comment: Thank you, the reference to that Enchanter feature definitively clears every doubt